# Access denied using F# CSVProvider

Tags: f#

I'm sure this is some sort of security issue.

In the second row I get the error System.UnauthorizedAccessException: 'Access to the path 'c:\csv\prices.csv' is denied.'  It's just a console app - how can I give my program access to that file?  I have tried adding "everyone" to the security on that folder with write access.

```
let saveCSV = new PriceItemType(priceRows) //prices.Append([p1])
saveCSV.Save("c:\\csv\\prices.csv")
```

Comment: Do you have that file open in another app, like Excel?

Comment: Also, you might want to check the exception's `Message` property for more information about the error.